# After uninstalling docker localhost redirects to localhost/tutorial from docker in nginx

Tags: docker, nginx, localhost, webserver

After i uninstalled docker on windows 10 and installed nginx, everytime i try to open localhost, redirect to localhost/tutorial from docker.

How do reverse this?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please update your question with the desired behavior, specific problems, and code to reproduce it. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Maybe it's the same problem as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63596057/localhost-redirecting-to-localhost-tutorial