# Localhost redirecting to localhost/tutorial

Tags: docker

Yo!

I am having an issue with my localhost after installing Docker Desktop. It automatically redirects to localhost/tutorial. I believe that is for the "beginner" container that comes with docker desktop, however even after removing it, and having other containers running, or even if docker is completely turned off, it still automatically redirects, which leads me to believe the issue is something with Windows.

I've checked my hosts file on windows and can't find anything wrong, but in case im being blind, this is the hosts file:

```
#
127.0.0.1 localhost
::1 localhost
# Added by Docker Desktop
192.168.68.116 host.docker.internal
192.168.68.116 gateway.docker.internal
# To allow the same kube context to work on the host and the container:
127.0.0.1 kubernetes.docker.internal
# End of section
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 30, accepted):

So turns out that it was indeed not windows, rather it was Google Chrome that had cached the redirect. So what you should do is go into the chrome settings and clean your cache, and that should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to clear cache then you can disable cache from network tab in chrome dev tools.

[Network tab screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oEXNF.png)