# Laravel sail. Redirect to docker tutorial page

Tags: laravel, docker, docker-compose, laravel-sail

I launch sail up for the first time, go to localhost and automatically redirects from http:// localhost/ to http://localhost/tutorial/. What could be the reason?  [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Zvid.png)

Comment: Is the tutorial running on port 80? What port is Sail on?

Comment: image: sail-8.0/app
        extra_hosts:
            - 'host.docker.internal:host-gateway'
        ports:
            - '${APP_PORT:-80}:80'
        environment:
            WWWUSER: '${WWWUSER}'
            LARAVEL_SAIL: 1
            XDEBUG_MODE: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_MODE:-off}'
            XDEBUG_CONFIG: '${SAIL_XDEBUG_CONFIG:-client_host=host.docker.internal}'

Comment: That doesn't necessarily mean it's running on port 80 - `docker container ls` will tell you what is actually mapped

Comment: displays port 80

Comment: Having the same problem. Some configuration is just wrong but no one figured it out yet.

Answer (score 0):

Someone figured out the problem is caused by the cache of your browser. The stackoverflow link is: [Localhost redirecting to localhost/tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63596057/localhost-redirecting-to-localhost-tutorial)
I tried this myself, it works very well.